# Wordpress conditional loop on a single page

Tags: wordpress, loops, conditional-statements

*Situation*: A page template contains pages with information about a topic and also runs a loop of posts about that topic - let's say: If is_page 'page1', show loop with tags about topic1 - If is_page 'page2', show loop with tags about topic2 ...

*Wanted solution*: I have +-25 pages about soccer teams that all need a loop with info about their specific team news(each team has a tag - not a category). But I only want to create 1 page template, because all the other information (the_content and some custom tags) is the similar for all pages.

*Tried*: I tried to fix this with get_template_part or get_query_var, but I cannot figure it out.

Any one can help me to get started?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a custom field to associate your page with a team, then loop on it.

Check about [Advanced Custom Field (ACF)](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), it's a must have plugin.